# Prevent Jquery Mobile from Truncating Text

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have simple tag to display text in a rounded box in jquery mobile but when I set the text property of the H tag in jquery the text gets truncated

```
<div data-role="page" id="question" data-position="fixed"  >
<div data-role="content"> 
<div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
    <h4 id="quest"></h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
//clearing the question box
$("#quest").empty();

$("#quest").append(questions[0].quest)
```

How do I prevent this behaivour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729146/how-to-stop-jquerymobile-from-truncating-text-in-label/15729272#15729272 this?

Comment: nope dats for a button class, the class for my rounded box is somethinglike ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow

Comment: i cant see any truncating http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AKb8r/

Comment: I have updated my question, the rounded box is a content div inside a jqm page

Comment: still the same, check the same link.

Comment: $("#quest").append(question[0].quest);

I think it's question ..in js you wrote "questions"

Comment: @Ani questions is an array dat i am setting the label to

Comment: What is question then?

Comment: @Omar I am clearing and resetting the label in jquery pogramatically could dat be the issue

Comment: how are you clearing it? pls post your code.

Comment: i still cant see the problem..http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AKb8r/

Answer (score 1):

there is a property into css:

```
.class{
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

ovveride it to change the style.